# PrintWriter: create a file in another package of the same project

Tags: java, file, url, printwriter

I'm trying to create and write on a file in another package using PrintWriter. This code doesn't seem to work though:

```
public void saveLevel() {
    PrintWriter writer;
    try {
        writer=new PrintWriter(new File
                (getClass().getResource("/sections/editor"+EditorPanel.LEVEL_NAME+".txt").getPath()));
        for(int i=0; i<ROWS; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<COLS; j++){
                if(!map[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("Bird") && !map[i][j].equalsIgnoreCase("Bear")){
                    writer.print(map[i][j]);
                }
            }
            writer.println();
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I end up with a null pointer exception on the "getClass().getResource()" line.

Comment: Do you know what `getResource()` does?

Comment: Don't confuse your project source code with your application's runtime environment and the classpath.

Comment: Resources are not files, and packages are not directories. Your application could/should be deployed as a JAR or WAR or EAR file, in which case resources and their locations are read-only.